# How can I post JSON to the server as a submit action?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an array of json objects in Javascript

`var myObjects = [{ ... }, { ... }, ...];`

I want to post this to the server, so that my controller can pick it up. The number of items in the array is variable.

I want to do it as if I were submitting a form, so the browser should redirect.

I can only think to do this with $.ajax and then do window.location to navigate on.

Is there a much cleaner way of doing this that I could be missing?

Comment: As far as I know, that's how you do it.

Comment: the only cleaner way is use the `action` of the form itself, that is pointing to your controller, and after process, it will show a `Thank you` view. You can have that json object as a `string` in a hidden input for example.

Comment: I could send the json to the server as a string in a form, but I want it to automatically map it to a complex object server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden input in your form. Encode to Json with `JSON.stringify(myObjects )`. Give hidden input a value of encoded string. In your controller decode with for example Newtonsoft.JSON which is available via NuGet

Server-side you can deserialize to your complex object with `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert<YourComplexObjectType>(string myObjects)`

Not for answer. If you want to work with your server-side objects on client side, give a try to [BreezeJs](http://www.breezejs.com/). It can map all your server-side objects to client-side js.